# How to addClass to a span element if validation was successful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to jQuery and trying to use it in validation of a register page.
This is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name</label>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" name="inputFirstName" placeholder="First name">
        <span class="" aria-hidden="true"></span> <-- this span
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$('#registration-form').validate({
    rules: {
        inputFirstName: {
            required: true,
        },

    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
        //want to remove 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' and then add some other class to span
    },
    success: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
        //want to insert 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' to span
    }
});
});
```

I want to add `glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback` to a span if validation was successful

I tried adding

`$(element).closest('span').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control- feedback");`

But it didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 
Give your span id

```
    <span class="" id="myspan" aria-hidden="true">
```

Step 2
Use addClass() method of jquery (shown below) inside success

```
<%--
Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
User: RaghavFTW
  Date: 04/07/15
  Time: 15:13
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<jsp:include page="../shared/header.jsp"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <form action="/register" id="registration-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Register</legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" name="inputFirstName"
                                   placeholder="First name">
                            <span class="" for="inputFirstName" id="spanFirstName" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputLastName" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" name="inputLastName"
                                   placeholder="Last name">
                            <span class="" for="inputLastName" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUsername" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" name="inputUsername"
                                   placeholder="Username">
                            <span class="" for="inputUsername" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword"
                                   placeholder="Password">
                            <span class="" for="inputPassword" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail"
                                   placeholder="Email">
                            <span class="" for="inputEmail" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Address</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <textarea style="max-width: 100%" class="form-control" rows="3" id="address"
                                      name="address"></textarea>
                            <span class="" for="address" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Gender</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male"
                                           checked="">
                                    Male
                                </label>
                                <br>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
                                    Female
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-8">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<jsp:include page="../shared/footer.jsp"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#registration-form').validate({
            rules: {
                inputUsername: {
                    minlength: 5,
                    required: true
                },
                inputPassword: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                inputEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                address: {
                    minlength: 10,
                    required: true
                },
                inputFirstName: "required",

            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
             //  var identify =  element.parent();
             //   console.log(identify);
             //   $("span[for='"+identify+"']").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control- feedback");
            },
            success: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
                $(element).remove();
                var identify =  element.attr("for");
                console.log(identify);
                $("span[for='"+identify+"']").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control- feedback");
            }
        });

        $('#search-form').validate({
            rules: {
                search: "required"
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            },
            success: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            }
        });

        $("input,textarea").change(function(){
            var identify =  this.id;
            console.log(identify);
            $("span[for='"+identify+"']").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback");
        });


    })
    ; // end document.ready
</script>
```

Comment: There will be more than just on form-control. Hence, more than one span.

Comment: then change $("#myspan") to $("span")...  :) i will update code, dont forget to upvote if ur happy :) thanks

Comment: That would do it for all the spans?

Comment: yes :) dont forget to select this as answer(upvote) if you are satisfied :) thanks

Comment: Ye, I don't want it for all the spans. I'm doing validation. If an input is valid I want to addClass to a span below that input. not all.

Comment: just give id to span that you want...example id="myspan", then use $("#myspan")... means if you want to add class to span below it, give id to that span and use $("#myspan").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback");  :) hope u understand :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82376/discussion-between-unni-babu-and-raghav-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$(element).closest('div[class="col-lg-6"]').find('span').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control- feedback");
```